# Присвоить переменной параметр функции JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции

При нажатии на кнопку вызывается функция с двумя аргументами - 5 и 9.
Как присвоить эти аргументы двум переменным?
Я новичок, документация не помогла.

```js
function step(a,b) {
   ???Код
}
var argA = ????
var argB = ???
```

```html
<button type="button"  onclick="step(4,9)">Кнопка</button>
```

Как присвоить `argA`, `argB` аргументы 4,9 ?
Выводить ничего не надо.

Comment: Скиньте свой код, чтобы вам возможно было помочь. На данный момент не совсем понятно, в чем именно у вас проблема..

Comment: Код функции в студию, пожалуйста. И листенер на нажатие кнопки тоже.

Comment: `var a = -5; var b = 9; (function(a, b){})(a, b);`

Comment: На ваш вопрос дали полноценный ответ, будьте любезны примите его, нажав на галочку под голосами. Таким способом вы говорите спасибо автору ответа на ru SO. По достижении необходимой репутации также сможете отдать свой голос за данный ответ или другой если такой будет

Answer (score 3):

```js
let перваяПеременная, втораяПеременная;

function функция(a, b) {
  перваяПеременная = a;
  втораяПеременная = b;
  console.log(перваяПеременная, втораяПеременная)
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  функция('перваяПеременная - ' + 5, ',  втораяПеременная - ' + 9)
})
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что было бы достаточно простой ссылки на учебник (например сюда [Внешние переменные](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) ). Помощь - это хорошо, но будет больше пользы, если научить "ловить рыбу" ;-)

Comment: А я по твоему печеную СЕМГУ на углях в сливочном соусе подал? ))

Comment: Ага. Да, ещё и разжёванную. Только проглотить осталось)))

Comment: ...........))))))))))))